# Correct GCP Load Balancer for External URLs

Tags: google-cloud-http-load-balancer

I send requests to external endpoints outside of Google Cloud from App Engine. The endpoint has limited quota for request count. I want to distribute my requests to multiple endpoints using Google Cloud load balancing. There are 30 different endpoints I can choose from.

Which type of Google Cloud load balancing route request to external endpoints?

How to create forwarding rules for different endpoints?

Does each endpoint cost as 1 rule or can I group into a pool?

Comment: Refer to this official docs  [doc 1](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-external-backend-internet-neg) [doc 2](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/forwarding-rule-concepts) for more information about  Application Load Balancer and forwarding rules